# Dot product of a time series of co-ordinates with a time series of rotation matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication, dot-product

I have a time series of spacecraft coordinates, which is of shape `(t,3)`, and a time series of rotation matrices of shape `(3,3,t)`, where *t* is the length of the time series. I want to find the dot product of the coordinates at each time *t* with the rotation matrix at each time *t*, such that I achieve an array of shape `(t,3)` which is the rotated coordinates.

I can achieve this in a for loop by writing:

```
new_coords = np.zeros_like(input_coords)
for Ci, Vi in enumerate(input_coords):
    new_coords[Ci,:] = np.tensordot(Vi, rotation[:,:,Ci], axes = 1)
```

How can I replace this for loop with a single line of Python? I've tried various permutations of `np.tensordot` with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ijk,ki->kj',rotation, input_coords)
```

Shapes in generic format -

```
rotation     : 3 x 3 x N
input_coords : N x 3
```

Two considerations were applied there -

- Sum-reduction of first (axes) of `rotation` with last of `input_coords`.
- Keeping the last of `rotation` and first of `input_coords` aligned. This is in correspondence with the way `Ci`  is used within the nested loop.